# How to access cPanel for a website hosted by FastHosts

Tags: web-hosting, phpmyadmin

I have picked up a website from a client, that a previous web developer had made. Its been moved to be hosted on fast hosts. However, I can't seem to access the CPanel.

I want access to the PHPMyAdmin area of my site.

I searched to see who the site is hosted by, and it comes up with 1and1. I also read somewhere that 1and1 own fasthosts, is this the case?

Comment: I found their documentation for accessing cPanel, is that what you are looking for? https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2172/~/accessing-whm-and-cpanel

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i have come across that, but the ip address with the 2087 port after it doesnt seem to work

Comment: 2087 is usually the WHM port

Answer (score 2):

According to [FastHosts](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2172/~/accessing-whm-and-cpanel), you can access cPanel in three steps:

> **Step 1:** Open an Internet browser and enter https://yourserverip:2083 replacing yourserverip with your server's IP address.
>
> **Step 2:** If this is the first time you have accessed cPanel, your browser will show a security warning. This is due to cPanel and WHM being secured using a self-signed certificate. Each browser will display a different message. In this example Chrome is used and the Proceed Anyway button.
>
> **Step 3:** Enter your username in the Username field and your password in the Password field. Click the Log in button to login.

In regards to your other question about whether or not "1and1 owns fasthosts," [United Internet](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2006/05/10/parent_of_11_internet_buys_uks_fasthosts.html) is the parent company of both 1&1 Internet and Fasthosts.